# Selecting columns from csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have the simple function that uses pandas:

```
def get_data(filename):
    '''function to read the data form the input csv file to use in the analysis'''
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = pd.read_csv(f, sep=',', usecols=('candidate',' final track' ,' status'))                      

        return reader
```

However, when I print reader, I get the columns that are two to the right of the columns I specified.

Why is this happening? And how can I correct it?
I'm new to pandas, so sorry for obvious mistakes

EDIT:

The first line of my csv file is:

candidate,     lead lag,     intensity,  width,  edgetrack,  track1 , track2,    edge track count,   track1 count,   track2 count,   final track,    status,     track 1 available,  track 2 available,  edges same as track 1,  edges same as track 2  , valid track

Comment: What is the form of the 1st line of your csv file? Also what happens if you pass a list of the cols like `usecols=['candidate',' final track' ,' status']`. I think we conversed before in a previous question and you said using absolute integer values worked e.g. `1,10,11` but column names didn't. What version of Pandas are you using?

Comment: Hi Ed, yes we did, this question was slightly different, so I wrote another one. First line= candidate  lead lag  intensity  width  edge track  track1  track2  edge track count  track1 count  track2 count  final track  status  track 1 available  track 2 available  edges same as track 1  edges same as track 2  valid track.
Square brackets gives me the dsame answer

Comment: [Previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979280/filtering-data-with-pandas).

Comment: @AshleighClayton what happens if you remove the space from `final track` so it becomes `final_track`? It is also possible to override the column names with your own `names= full_list_col_names` and also pass `usecols=cols_of_interest` but this seems overkill to me. Could you try renaming the cols to replace the spaces with underscores

Comment: @AshleighClayton I just created a temp csv file with the same column headers as yours and used the same `usecols` parameter as yours and this worked fine in Pandas 0.12. What version are you using?

Comment: 0.12.0. h'mm what code are you using?

Comment: it's working! bizarre. Must have missed something out somewhere. Do those names now act as index?

Comment: @AshleighClayton yes you can pass integer values or the names in a list (and apparently a tuple). I was using `temp = read_csv(r'c:\temp\new  2.txt', usecols=['candidate',' final track' ,' status'])` so nothing special

Comment: read_csv has argument skipinitialspace, maybe that what you need? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html?highlight=read_csv